# Android Studio design display

Tags: java, android

[screenshot of android studio problem design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpaMm.jpg)
[image]

Why the design of XML Activity doesn't appear in Android studi?

Comment: Verify gradle sync issue, this issue is not allowing IDE build your project.

Comment: click on android symbol where it shows null and select an api level there

Answer (score 0):

Your application generate an error for that reason your build is broken. 
Try to fix that error and run build again.